# Where should table filters and search be placed?

Tags: search, tables, filter, placement

Any ideas on whether filters should be on the left or right of a table? What about search?

They both narrow down the contents of what's in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is the only element displayed on the page, filters should be in a right or left column. and for tablet/mobile, just above the page title.[image]

Comment: upvoted! how should this work, should this filter rows inside the table or should this load a dropdown with filtered options clicking which takes you to a new page

Answer (score 1):

I'd put them at the right if you must choose. Unless you *really* need to filter your data to make sense of it, I'd tuck it out of the left-gutter view most people scan with.

I've also has some really interesting usability sessions that suggest filters/search are confusing for non-techy people whom may rather just scroll. This all depends on the size of your list and target audience, but I highly suggest testing your design against users.

Another thought is to de-emphasize the sort/filters/search until needed and then perhaps on hover making them more prominent.